# Bootstrap: navbar header button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer to the code fragment below. It is a simple navbar.

Unfortunately, the collapse-toggle button appears above the brand (because it breaks the line, behaving like a block), what is unexpected. The expected behavior is that it appears beside. Further, if I try to float it with `.navbar-right`, it doesn't work. What could it be?

http://jsfiddle.net/X3pVX/

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Projeto Si</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form form-inline navbar-right">
                <div class="input-group" style="max-width: 400px">
                    <input id="filter" class="form-control input-sm" type="text" placeholder="O que você está procurando?"/>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button id="clearfilter" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey whats sup? I'm from Brazil too.

You only have the html file?
if yes you need to use css. never use style on html, HTML is for content and CSS for style.

create a css file and put the code below between the head tag.

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FileName.css" />
</head>
```

after that choose the class that you want to modify the position and try the code below

```
.navbar-right {

 position:absolute;
 left:150px;

}
```

try different pixels values and see which one works better for you.

If you don't know anything about css i recommend http://www.w3schools.com/
study there just for have a notion.

Comment: I have a CSS file. Ignore this. I just want to know about the bootstrap specific question.

Comment: The question has to do with Twitter Bootstrap, which is already in it's own CSS. Also http://www.w3fools.com/